# W8 and status change

Tags: united-states, taxes

What happens if there is a status change (from nonresident alien to resident alien) in terms of a W8 (as filled out at a bank)? I guess that this would occur pretty frequently (since after 5 years on a visa like F1 you are considered resident alien) but there is zero information out there. I wonder even more *why is there no information*?

**Background**: About 1.5 years ago I opened a bank account and got an opening bonus - parts of it was payed last year. I remember filling out a W8 form which is for *nonresident aliens*. This year I need to file as *resident alien* for the first time. I vaguely remember that the account opening bonus would need to be taxed and started looking for an 1099-INT which I never received. After many emails, phone calls and personal visits in the bank branch, the bank still insists that I would not get a 1099-INT and I would not need to pay tax on this bonus.

Comment: I’m no expert on non-resident taxes, but I think you need to go to the bank and fill out a W-9, to indicate that you are now a resident. (This has nothing to do with interest received last year, but rather for interest that you will receive in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

The part of the bonus you received in 2017, as well as any interest you received in 2017, should be reported as interest on your 2017 tax return, even if you didn’t receive a 1099 for it.